# Windows PostgreSQL Update Timezone Data

Tags: postgresql, timezone, windows-server

Turkey government has announced that Turkey will stay on GMT+3.

We've waited for OS pathces to update tzdata on PostgreSQL.
Now, timezone patch for Windows is installed.

On **Linux**, restarting PostgreSQL service is enough.
But on **Windows**, restarting did not help.

```
postgres=#select extract(timezone from '2017-01-01'::timestamptz);
date_part
---------
7200
```

On **linux**;

```
postgres=#select extract(timezone from '2017-01-01'::timestamptz);
date_part
---------
10800
```

I need to update timezone datas for PostgreSQL on **Windows**.

Can anyone help me to solve this?

Also I am sure that timezone change patch is installed.[image: Windows Clock&Date Information]

*PostgreSQL versions are 9.2 and 9.5*

Comment: What does `SHOW timezone;` say?

Comment: TimeZone is set to Turkey

Comment: Try to upgrade PostgreSQL to the latest releases (9.2.18 and 9.5.4) if you do not do it yet.

Comment: I've tried fresh installation of 9.5.4 but it did not help.

Comment: As I know the timezone data is incompiled into the PostgreSQL windows version. So you need to wait a bit for the new release. [Update time zone data files to tzdata release 2016g](https://git.postgresql.org/gitweb/?p=postgresql.git;a=commit;h=ecbac3e6e038e990f24a2e0eacdcd6738292105f)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Today PostgreSQL released new minor versions.
In these versions timezone datas updated to 2016h.

Released versions;

- [9.6.1](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/release-9-6-1.html)
- [9.5.5](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/release-9-5-5.html)
- [9.4.10](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/release-9-4-10.html)
- [9.3.15](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/release-9-3-15.html)
- [9.2.19](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/release-9-2-19.html)

Also you don't have to upgrade your installation.

You can move new timezone datas to your installation and restart the service.
It's all done.
It's worth the wait.

Comment: You should nevertheless upgrade the whole installation. [Quote from the homepage](https://www.postgresql.org/support/versioning/): "*The community considers **not** upgrading [to a higher minor version] to be riskier than upgrading*"